# Setting dojo calendar format

Tags: javascript, dojo, calendar

I'm geting the value in `dijit.Calendar` in dojo v. 1.6

now it's return

```
Mon Mar 19 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0700 (SE Asia Standard Time)
```

Can I changing the format to `yyyy-MM-dd` ?

I'm try to add

```
<div id="mainCalendar" dojotype="dijit.Calendar" constraints="{datePattern:'yyyy-MM-dd', strict:true}"></div>
```

but not worked.

Comment: Can you show a fully working example, perhaps on JSFiddle? Are you creating your widget using declarative style aor are you using the programatic style?

Comment: @missingno I'm using declarative style. Now I have edited my code,  please let's see it again.

Comment: Note that this is a Date object, and you're looking at the toString() value.  Also, the constraints attribute isn't relevant to the Calendar widget.  Perhaps you're thinking of dijit.form.DateTextBox?

Comment: @peller thanks peller.But in my case can not use dijit.form.DateTextBox. Because of the user requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I can found the way.

This code will return the data with new format

Add this code in the function, at `onChange event` called.

```
var theValue = dojo.date.locale.format(arguments[0], {
    formatLength: 'short',
    selector:'date',datePattern:'yyyy-MM-dd'
});
```

[Have a look to this @jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YApwK/6/)

*Work at testing on dojo 1.6 and 1.7.2*

Comment: note that formatLength and datePattern are mutually exclusive in their intent.  formatLength seeks to pick a culturally-appropriate "short" date format, while datePattern overrides with a specific date pattern which will be used regardless of locale.

Answer (score 0):

The default format is related to locale.
If you want to change default date format, modify the date format in the localised date config file: **dojo/cldr/nls/${your_language}/gregorian.js**

It worked for me